# RethinkDB Proxy on app server with automatic startup

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, startup, rethinkdb

So, I have:

- 4 nodes in a sharded / replicated cluster (4 shards, 2 replicas per shard)
- 2 app servers running tornado + rethink in proxy only mode

**How can we make Rethink start automatically but in proxy mode?**

I manage to run it manually and it connects to my 4 nodes using /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/proxy.conf (for example), but I haven't found anywhere in the documentation how to configure it for automatic startup.

My tornado processes talk to the cluster only via the local proxy, everything works fine.

*FYI, all my servers run Ubuntu.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have a configuration in `instances.d` that works, try shutting down any instances of RethinkDB on the command line that might be using the same ports and run `sudo /etc/init.d/rethinkdb restart`; I think that should cause RethinkDB to start automatically thereafter.

Comment: yes, but in that case it starts as DB server and not as proxy

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant when you said "I manage to run it manually and it connects to my 4 nodes using /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/proxy.conf (for example), but I haven't found anywhere in the documentation how to configure it for automatic startup."

I asked around and it seems like right now the only thing to do is write your own startup script (or edit the RethinkDB one to run `rethinkdb proxy` instead).  There's an issue at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5138 to make this easier that you can track.

Comment: yes, I finally created my own init.d script and it works

Comment: @Apero can you please show the relevant part of you init.d, I am not so great at scripting.